# Prove the limit of $\frac {1}{x^2}$ as $x$ approaches $\sqrt {3}$ equals $\frac {1}{3}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I need to show that $0<|x-\sqrt3|<δ$ implies $|{1 \over x^2}-{1 \over 3}|<ɛ$.

The first step I took was to take the reciprocal of $|{1 \over x^2}-{1 \over 3}|$ as this equals $|(x^2)-3|$, however this where I am stuck, because taking the reciprocal of an inequality causes the inequality sign to flip, which would make $|(x^2)-3| > {δ \over 1}$. if the function can't be greater than delta what do I do?

Comment: You made the Freshman's Dream mistake. $\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)^{-1} \neq a+b$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: The reciprical of $|\frac 1{x^2} - \frac 13| =\frac 1{|\frac 1{x^2} - \frac 13|}\ne |x^2 - \frac 13|$.  Instead $|\frac 1{x^2} - \frac 13| = |\frac {3-x^2}{3x^2}|$.  And the reciprical of that is $|\frac {3x^2}{3-x^2}|$ which isn't useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\forall \epsilon > 0$, let $\delta = \min \left( \frac{3}{4} \epsilon,2-\sqrt{3} \right)$, then:

$$\left| x - \sqrt{3} \right| < \delta \rightarrow$$
$$\left| \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{3} \right| = \left| \frac{3-x^2}{3x^2} \right| = \left| \frac{(\sqrt{3}-x)(\sqrt{3}+x)}{3x^2} \right| < \left| \frac{(\delta)(4)}{3} \right| = \epsilon$$

EDIT:  I edited the above to define $\delta$ so that $x \in (1,2)$, rather than say "when $x \in (1,2)$, which it eventually will be as $x \to \sqrt{3}$.”

Intuition:

I knew that I would have $\left| x - \sqrt{3} \right| < \delta$, and that ideally I wanted to factor $\left| \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{3} \right|$ to be $\textit{something}$ times $\left| x - \sqrt{3} \right|$.  Seeing the $x^2$ and $3$, my intuition was that I wanted $\left| (x - \sqrt{3})( x + \sqrt{3} )\right|$ in the numerator, which I could get by combining the fractions over a common denominator

Next, having $\left| x - \sqrt{3} \right| < \delta$, I still needed to find an upper bound for $\left| x + \sqrt{3} \right|$, and a lower (since it's in the denominator) bound for $3x^2$.  Since $x \to \sqrt{3}$, I knew that it would eventually be in $(1,2)$, and integers are easier to deal with (for me at least), so I knew $3x^2 > 3$ (since $x>1$), and $( x + \sqrt{3} ) < 2+\sqrt{3} < 4$ (since $x<2$).

That is how I reached the part:

$$< \left| \frac{(\delta)(4)}{3} \right|$$

Now, to figure out what $\delta$ needs to be, I just solve for the $\delta$ to make:

$$ \left| \frac{(\delta)(4)}{3} \right| = \epsilon$$

Which is how I got $\delta = \frac{3}{4}\epsilon$.

Also, since I want $x \in (1,2)$, then I can require that formally by ensuring that $\delta \leq 2-\sqrt{3}$, hence let $\delta = \min \left( \frac{3}{4} \epsilon,2-\sqrt{3} \right)$.

This is how many of these continuity proofs work:

Step 1:  Write $\forall \epsilon > 0$, let $\delta = ?$ (figure out the $\delta$ in step 5).

Step 2: Write:

$$\left| x - a \right| < \delta \rightarrow$$
$$\left| f(x) - f(a) \right| =$$

Step 3: Continue that expression, rearranging using algebra, often factoring to get $\textit{something}$ times $\left| x - a \right|$.

Step 4: Figure out a bound on that $\textit{something}$

Step 5: Now, figure out what $\delta$ needs to be in terms of $\epsilon$, so that, when mulplied by that $\textit{something}$, you get a value less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: How did you get δ = 3ϵ/4

Comment: @Reginald Bompers, I added an explanation for my intuition on these types of problems.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome!